# Wrong value from application-test.yaml

Tags: java, properties, yaml

I try to use parameter `dayPeriod` from yaml file:

application-test.yml

```
app-config:
 operations:
  dayPeriod: 10
```

OperationProperties.java

```
@Component
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app-config.operations")
public class OperationProperties {
    private int dayPeriod;
}
```

But when I try to get value from OperationProperties.java I receive 0 instead 10

TimeUtilsTest.java

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class TimeUtilsTest {
   private final OperationProperties operationProperties = new OperationProperties();

   @Test
   void test(){
       System.out.println(operationProperties.getDayPeriod); // print: 0
   }

}
```

Why I get wrong value?

Comment: Hello, YAML syntax is with two spaces indentation. You have only one.

Comment: @Mar-Z it's a mistake in question. I using two spaces in code

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@Autowired` instead of `new OperationProperties();`

```
@Autowired
OperationProperties operationProperties;
@Test
public void testConf(){
    int dayPeriod = operationProperties.getDayPeriod();
    System.out.println(dayPeriod);
    assert dayPeriod==10;
}
```

The reason why you get 0 is `new OperationProperties();` this will result in a new object, rather than getting it from the springboot container,because dayPeriod is of type int, there will be a default value of 0.

Comment: but when I using @Autowired (with `@Component` annotation) I receive NullPointerException :(